# How to assign values from an array to textviews  in android

Tags: android, arrays, textview

I have 4 textview such as t11,t12,t13,t14 and I have also 4 value in array val[4].

I want to store these values randomly in textviews. but I am getting little problem.

I have done following code:

```
  TextView t11,t12,t13,t14;
  Random r = new Random();

  for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        int val[4]=r.nextInt(10);
        Log.d("horror", "Randm Array of VAL:" +val[i]);
  }
```

In the Log,there are 4 values displayed but how to display them in textviews.

I have coded but it does not work properly.

```
  t1[i+1].setText("" +val[i]);
```

and 
      In this case,values are properly displayed, but i want to do code optimization.

```
  t11.setText("" +val[0]); 
  t12.setText("" +val[1]); 
  t13.setText("" +val[2]);
  t14.setText("" +val[3]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store their references inside an array , it won't create new objects. so this should do the job

```
  TextView [] textviews = {t11,t12,t13,t14};
    for(int i =0;i<textviews.length;++i){
    textviews[i].setText(val[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Every time you loop in **`for`**, you create another integer array. Take the definition of **`val`** out of the **`for`** loop.

Answer (score 1):

For your TextView use something like,

```
TextView [] tv = {t11,t12,t13,t14};
```

and use **tv** for other going stuff... So now, you can getting it work by,

```
tv[i+1].setText("" +val[i]);
```